# How to transfer files from Galaxy s7

Tags: samsung

I had a galaxy s7 until i dropped it and the LCD broke.  The screen is black but the phone is on.  To repair it is $250, Id rather not pay that.  But I need my files from my phone.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that. You can connect your phone to a pc or Mac to transfer files from your phone.

You can find it below.
https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840804?hl=en

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, everytime I plugged my phone into my computer, my computer couldnt find my phone.  My computer would say to plug my phone in using a USB cord.